# dtruss SQL-Queries on Mac OSX

Tags: linux, macos, mac, strace

In our shop we have an inhomogenous environment and doing Java on different boxes - mostly Mac OSX, me on Linux and one Windows box.
When it comes to debugging JPQL-Queries and its SQL-outcome, there is the need to read *plain SQL*. I found one possibility in using the _general_log_ in msql and let the server do the query logging. But I am a lazy developer, so I thought about a *faster approach* to get *direct results*.

On my *Linux-box* I simply `strace -p $CATALINAsPID -f -q - s 9999 - e sendto` and let my query run. `sendto` is the system call which contains the *plain SQL*.

I wanted to do the same for Mac OSX and found `dtruss` (a fassade for *dtrace*?) , which does similar things like `strace`. So I tried to narrow it down to `sendto` (analog to Linux) - but without success.

How does dtruss work, resp: how do I trace the *plain SQL*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hacky way, to get, what I want:
Simply write a dtrace script like:

```
syscall::sendto:entry
/pid == $setPIDHere/
{
    tracemem((copyin(arg1, arg2)),9999);
}
```

And grab the result. Hacky, but works